# PHP Shopping Cart Problem

Tags: php, javascript, web, shopping-cart

Okay, so I have a shopping cart problem.

I've decided to roll out my own cart, which is alot easier than I had expected. BUT, I've run into a problem and cannot for the life of me figure out what to do next.

The problem:

After adding products to the cart, the user is taken to a "checkout" page, where they edit the quantities of the items they want.

These items are displayed in a table.

How can I get these items with their edited/new values into a PHP variable, and then update the corresponding entries in the database?

The page in question is:

But to actually see stuff in the "checkout" page, you'll need to visit:

http://www.com.au/.php     and click on a few prices, and then click "Place Order" link just above the table.

Any help/advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to add a input variable.

```
<tr>
    <td>Cool Item</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='items[<?=$product_id;?>]' value='1' /></td>
</tr>
```

Then check the $_POST['items'] array.

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $product_ID=>$quanity) {
    proccessItem($product_ID, $quanity);
}
```

Comment: This is what I need, thank you so much! If I have followup questions, would you mind? :)

Comment: sure, just shoot me the question and I'll respond asap

Comment: @webbiedave, ofcourse :). It says I still have 3minutes before I can mark it as answer.

Comment: @sean, i have a strange problem. the items in the table are dynamically generated at runtime, and i wrap the <form> tags around the table. But the form doesn't appear to work at all. And nothing actually gets posted. Not sure if I should have this as a new question or not. or maybe just update this question with the code?

Comment: Awesome, and done! Here is the link, if you are able to have a look :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189771/problems-with-form-and-dynamically-generated-links

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a form that post onto the page to change the values in the database. Another option would be to use an Ajax request if you do not want the page to reload on update.

I would say in this instance you would want add a remove from cart button and a onkeyup event to your quantity box that would then be handled through Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but am answering because you appreciate any help. :-)

Are you using session.

create a session array for keep the selected items

when ever user edit his cart update thats session array.

show items from that array. at last when he check out post data into db from this session array.

i found an error on website

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\web\onestopf\checkout.php on line 55

Then on that row count now its 10,20,23.  10,20,30 will be better :-)