# Problems with <form> and Dynamically-generated links

Tags: php, javascript, forms, web, shopping-cart

Related directly to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189522/php-shopping-cart-problem), I am having trouble implementing some sound advice given from @sean, because as you can see on this page:

http://www.onestopfasteners.com.au/checkout.php     - I have wrapped the form tags around the table element, but the form just doesn't seem to be working, and nothing ever gets "POST"ed either. I've changed the code around abit to experiment, but haven't found a solution, and no search anywhere has proven to be useful yet.

I'd appreciate any help at all. I'm completely baffled!

Thanks!

P.S. I thought that maybe the fact that I am wrapping form elements around dynamically generated content could be why the form isn't working, but that doesn't make much sense to me and, I've done it before, so that can't be it, can it?

### Code:

I know, it's long, apologies in advance. :)

```
<?php
   // (c) code removed ;) problem solved - thanks to everyone who helped!
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with:

```
function submit() {

             document.myform.submit();

             }
```

Try:

```
function submit() {

                 document.getElementById('ct_form').submit();

                 }
```

It looks like you are using jQuery in the page so you could also use:

```
function submit() {
    $('#ct_form').submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) - I will try that. And by "ct_form" do you mean "myform" as I already have?

Comment: No, your form in the html has the `id` attribute set to 'ct_form' and not 'myform'. That is why your code is not working because 'myform' does not exist.

Comment: Unless of course you have changed the `id` since I viewed the source of the link you provided in your question! :)

Comment: Ah, no I haven't changed it since, I just got myself a little confused when reading the code I posted above :P My eyes tend to wander around sometimes lol. Well, I tried adding 'ct_form', and it appears to have done something! So thanks!!! :D Now I can go n add the rest of the php stuff then all good thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your using javascript to submit the form, but you are referencing document.myform which doesn't exsist.

try this instead.

```
document.getElementById('ct_form').submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// do sumbit first form of document 
document.forms[0].submit()
```

`document.getElementById` is not necessary here. `document.myform` relies on `NAME` attribute of `FORM` element, by the way